# What material can I use as a temporary window pane?

Tags: windows

I may have a renter moving into a condo in a couple of weeks. I already ordered a full window replacement for the bedroom. Since a pane of glass (3' x 4') is missing, I'm thinking to put on a plastic or glass like material just for a couple of weeks instead of wasting $150 for a real pane of glass and throw it away after two weeks. Of course this will happen with the tenant's consent.

Is there material like that? Where can I buy it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common temporary fix I see is a piece of plywood.  This is one of the cheapest, but is not the most aesthetic solution.

If you go to a company that sells glass and mirror you will find much better prices opposed to something that you would purchase at a hardware store or online.

Glass is much cheaper than plastic.  You can go with a piece of DS (double strength 1/8") glass as a temporary solution as long as it is not in a location that is required to be safety glass according to building code.

Comment: You are right, I talked to a glass shop and they offered, if I take the window frame to their shop, they would put a pane of glass on it for $25, labor included.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy big sheets of plexi at big-box hardware stores, or online cut to size. A simple websearch for "plexiglass sheet" turned up a large number of wholesalers.

However, the cost may surprise you; a 36" x 48" x 1/4" sheet was $100 at the random [place I checked.](http://www.professionalplastics.com/PLEXIGLASS-ACRYLICSHEET-EXTRUDED)

Still, afterward you'll have a huge piece of very durable plexiglass that you could use for something else.

Comment: Along those lines...If the window isn't larger than a poster, you can get a $10 poster frame from Target and use the plastic that's in that.